# Should I accept a job if pair programming is required?

Tags: agile, pair-programming

I have been offered an interesting job, but there's a big caveat for me: they use pair programming.

I hate the idea of pair programming, and I'm probably not suited for it: I like to do frequent pauses, I hate to see someone programming (I would constantly poke the pair away to code myself), I have to be in full control of the machine I'm working on, I like to work listening music, and basically I don't like to being tied to someone else. I'm not even a social person.

I have however never actually worked with true pair programming (besides few times for a short time to help someone else or to solve a complex task together)... so it is pair programming really that bad? And given my attitude, should I refuse the job or should I leave my current one and give a try?

---

For people that asked about it: I'm looking for a job where formal design and development are used, as I hate my current job where we are "coding in the wild". The company is very interested in my technical profile so they insisted even when I specified I never worked with pair programming and that I probably wouldn't like it (besides being an unsociable loner programmer, I don't like and believe the very concept of pair programming).

Comment: Well, you personally don't sound even a little keen on it, so I don't think you should do it unless you want to give it the old college try.

Comment: I find a compromise between total pair programming and solo programming is a nice mix.  You get the benefit of a second set of eyes but also get some space and room to breath the other half of the time.

Comment: ITs usefull when you are new to that coding language ... you can get help right away .. you dont need to wait for ppl to reply On SO :P

Comment: What really sucks is if you don't type fast and the other guy does. Makes you all nervous and then you make typing mistakes and then you're hunting for the backspace key and hitting delete instead. What a mess...

Comment: @Lorenzo, what did you decide in the end, and how did it turn out?

Comment: @Benjol: I've tried for a few weeks (I was able to keep my existing job in standby in the meantime) and then I realized that I really hate pair programming, so I went back to my old job.

Comment: From what you said, I think that you did the right thing. However, I imagine that you are also now looking for what you really wanted - "I'm looking for a job where formal design and development are used, as I hate my current job where we are "coding in the wild".".

Comment: Just so you feel better, I refused to go forward when I heard I have to use the same keyboard shortcuts and IDE and theme. It was the interview where I was already offered. Because pair programming with too much sharing is not very good idea.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Based on your various comments here, you seem to to have a similar outlook/disposition to myself on the subject. And I *have* experienced "Pair Programming". And I certainly wouldn't join a company that required me to bite a scorpion. :)

What I'd recommend is: Go with your gut.

If the company would force you to do Pair Programming and you know you don't want to, don't join.

If they'll give you the opportunity to show that you can produce better work faster than any two of their current developers combined, go ahead and prove it.

Before you decide for definite though, I'd certainly agree with the recommendation that you ask to talk to the existing developers there, and get a feel for them as people. (I'd probably recommend that for any new job, regardless of the methodologies used.)

Answer (score 32):

Guess what - **nobody likes pair programming at first**.

When I first tried pair programming I was against the idea and I had tons of objections similar to yours.  I don't like to watch someone else coding, I like to listen to music, I feel I'll be quicker working on my own, I don't want to stop and explain myself constantly, etc etc etc.

Then I tried it.  And guess what?  **It still sucked**.  We were having all kinds of problems - I wanted to work **different hours** to the other guy, we had different **keyboard settings** and shortcuts, our **desks** didn't work very well for pair programming etc etc.

This went on for about a week.  During that week we were rewriting the entire legacy login system for a distributed application.  We had to learn how some seriously difficult threading issues work, figure out how remoting sinks worked, change tons and tons of legacy code to work with our new login module and pretty much do some of the most hectic coding I've had to do in my career.  After a week of this we deployed it.. and **everything just worked**.  *Not a single bug*.  **Not one**.

That's when I figured there might be something to this pair programming nonsense.  We started to do more pair programming.  We even started to force everyone to work in pairs.  It rocked.  *I probably learnt more in a month of doing that than I did in the previous 2 years*.  The other issues didn't go away.  Sometimes you'll be stuck with a pair that you dislike.  It's gonna happen.  Sometimes you'll struggle to find overlapping working hours.  Sometimes you'll want to just work on your own.  But the advantages of pair programming are just incredible.

Since then I've always tried to do as much pair programming as possible.  It's simply the best way of learning.  This company forces everyone to do pair programming? **Where do I sign up?**  It seems to me they are really enlightened and you will be in a really intense working environment.  Awesome.

Having said that, make sure that the pairs are rotated often.  You don't want to be stuck developing with one other developer for months on end - you'll go out of your mind.  We're all human, after all.  Also, check that this has been an ongoing practice for a while.  If it's not, it's not the end of the world, but if it's an accepted practice it's a massive green light.

### Trust me, you want to work for a company like that.

Comment: I would suggest that the OP will only succeed at a company like this if he's open to learning that he's not actually as good at programming as he thinks he is, and then comes around to wanting to learn how to get better.

Comment: They basically told me your same exact story. People there were very supportive and I acknowledge that coding that way rocks - and improves your skills. But that was driving me crazy. I couldn't live with all the limitations to my "personal freedom"  and "living space" (choosing the timing, listening to music, keyboard configuration, color scheme in the IDE etc.), so after few weeks I give up.

Comment: "After a week of this we deployed it.. and everything just worked. Not a single bug. Not one.": I haven't experienced a significant difference in number of bugs between using pair-programming and not using it. Discussing the essential points with your colleagues and then coding on your own can be as effective. Pair-programming is no silver bullet.

Comment: I recently completed my first project using pair programming with a more senior developer in the team. We shared the piloting and co-piloting of complex tasks fairly evenly and we both learned a few things from each other. We did split for trivial, mundane or "boiler-plate" tasks.

Comment: I found pair programming on this project helped me not go down blind alleys and rabbit holes that I have been prone to on single developer projects. When the project was released the project had lest bugs in test and the warranty period than any other of it's size in the company. We also have two developers who know the product intimately so the "hit by a bus" problem is less critical.

Comment: I for one now ONLY want to program in a pair as the knowledge transfer is amazing, both for coding skills and IDE shortcuts.

And for those germophobes - plug in your own keyboard and mouse and stick to your own when you are the driver!

Comment: "Guess what - nobody likes pair programming at first.": Guess what - I did not like it after doing it for two years on a row. I left that company and in my new company / team **nobody** wants to do pair programming and we are all very happy and much more productive. In my experience, pair programming is only good for training beginners, for micromanaging, or for people who are not able to work on their own.

Comment: Guess What, We always have been doing pair programming in some ways

Answer (score 19):

Pair programming is a great tool! It can be way more efficient – two heads are better than one – and a great way to learn new techniques. Of course, there are other benefits too. But, if you are not buying into it, then you won’t get anything out of it. Given your attitude, it sounds like you would not fit into it at all and it would probably be a waste of time. It looks like your mind is already made up before you even give it a shot.

Comment: Two heads are also twice as expensive, and that's the big downside =) But this concerns the company not you

Comment: -1 Is pair programming great? It is the worst thing ever happened in my working life!

Comment: With pair programming, you definitely have to keep an open mind. We do it in our office a bit (not officially), and it seems to help in some cases. I tend to agree with this wiki article on the benefits of pair programming, but YMMV: http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?PairProgrammingBenefits

Comment: Pair programming should be used on difficult tasks. That's when you're saving money and time. Otherwise it's kind of a waste. I like it though.

Comment: I think it should also be used as a mentoring tool for "greenhorns" to help them until they get the hang of real-world coding.

Comment: @Kop: I disagree. The goal of pair programming is precisely that two heads **together** create better software than the same two heads each on their own, while begin just as expensive. (That is, of course, if you aren't reaching that goal, then it is not worth it).

Comment: @Sergio Acosta: Two heads together does not imply you do all the coding together. You can also discuss the architecture together, divide the code into submodules, define interfaces, and then do the coding on your own while respecting the interfaces. I did this many times and it can be much more efficient than sitting together for hours on the same code.

Comment: I don't like generalizations. And two heads are not per se better than one, even if that statement claims that. There are (great) programmers who depend on their solo-thinking-time, who don't want (or can) care for the co-pilot. Who function best in a fire-and-forget manner; that does not imply they don't like to meet up every few hours. Not every task is best executed by two; consider for example race driving: the hotlapping part of race driving is not benefited by a co-driver. There are team-radios for the bigger picture, but not in every single corner.

Answer (score 11):

I tried pair programming and hated it. I share almost all the doubts and concerns you have expressed against it. I resigned for this very reason.

My personal advice is always against pair, and given your attitude I strongly advice you to not even give it a try.

Comment: +1 for honesty.  :)  It's not for everyone, indeed.

Comment: @Wizard: Some people like pair programming, I don't. I prefer to discuss the structure of the code in advance, then do the coding, then do a code review. This puts a filter between myself and my colleagues so that we only exchange relevant information.

Comment: @Wizard: I find with pair programming you discuss too many insignificant details: there is a lot of noise that slows down your train of thoughts and makes you less efficient. Other people find it stimulating and like the unstructured but continuous feedback they get. Some people say I am an individualist, I object that you can work as a team and still be structured, in the same way as a soccer team occupy the whole playground instead of going all where the ball is. Anyway, I think it is a matter of how each programmer works and not all programmers work in the same way.

Answer (score 10):

Let's look at this from another POV: given your predisposition, you're likely doing a disservice to the employer.  They certainly don't want to hire someone who "hates" one of their development practices.  Have you informed them of your perspective given such a tight-collaborative environment?  If not, you're potentially misrepresenting yourself.

As an employer, I would be pretty frustrated to hire someone who knew, coming in, that they wouldn't be happy with the development practices we had put into place.  It's a recipe for discontentment and frustration for everyone involved.

---

**Edit**
Given that they understand where you're coming from (and are willing to take you on, as you mentioned in your comment), why not discuss how you feel with a few developers in the company?  It's possible they'll be able to address any concerns or biases you have against PP.  It's also important for them to know you're not terribly keen on the idea since you'll be working with them full-time.

It will also give you an opportunity to learn something about the people you'll be working with so closely.

If everyone is on board, I would certainly advocate PP for the same reasons mentioned in the answers here.  You have immediate accountability for what you're writing; another set of eyes on your code will likely catch defects or trouble-spots you might otherwise miss; you get great exposure to someone else's perspective on coding (and get to provide your own experience); and the end result is very often much better than you would expect.

I appreciate your bias against PP; there are times I want nothing more than to sit at a computer banging away at a problem, and PP gets frustrating (I'm also an introvert, which means PP leaves me feeling a bit more drained at the end of the day) because someone is always there.  This said, the results, in my experience, speak for themselves and I'm much more amicable to it on a regular basis.

Comment: I talked about it to the employer, and they asked me to try.

Comment: @Lorenzo, fantastic. It's so important to accurately represent yourself to an employer, and if they're willing to let you give it a try, then it's something to consider.

Comment: that's why I don't have already refused the job, however leaving the current job for something I probably will not like scares me a lot...

Answer (score 5):

I recently went to a pair-programming code retreat. I don't use it at work and am very new to it. I am like you in the sense that I like to have control of my own machine. Several programmers who pair-program a lot kept stressing that **pair-programming significantly improves one's coding skills** because you get constant feedback, your code is being consistently reviewed, and you are less likely to write hacky code.
I agree with the fact that it is a significant change for someone who has never pair-programmed before. However, it is hard to have a strong opinion on the matter unless you try it for an extended period of time.

Comment: When I have to assist a coworker, or even to stay next to him for a couple of minutes, I have to keep my mouth close, otherwise I would start criticizing every single line of code...

Comment: @Lorenzo so you're ok giving criticism but not receiving it?

Comment: @dash-tom-bang: actually I just avoid giving criticism at all, or I would criticize every line of code...

Comment: If yielding to your criticisms would make the code substantially better, you should give them.  If your criticisms' suggestions make no positive impact then you should figure out why you feel compelled to make them.

Answer (score 5):

> I hate the idea of pair programming

...

> I never actually worked with pair programming

You must clarify that first.

You can't say you dislike something without trying it. I personnaly disliked tomato sauce until I actually tasted it.

Comment: Tomato sauce is just tomato soup without the spices... Or ketchup without the sugar and vinegar. :)

Comment: I never tried it but I know the idea and concept of pair programming and don't like it. You don't really have to be bitten by a scorpion to know you'll not like it!

Comment: How do you know that? You might *love* being bitten by a scorpion! ;)

Comment: I sure you all understood the message

Comment: Pierre, there's a difference between understanding and agreement, and just because you incorrectly extrapolated how tomato sauce tasted doesn't mean Lorenzo is doing the same with Pair Programming. :P

Sure, he *might* be, it might be solely down to the people he's worked with that he feels the way he does, but it's certainly *possible* to determine if that's the case without actually experiencing 'true' pair programming.

Answer (score 5):

You sound like you are definitely not psyched to do pair programming, but the fact that you asked the question would lead me to believe that you're keeping an open mind to it.

Why not be up-front with the employer and let him know how you feel.  If they still think you are the candidate that they want then you could suggest a 2 week trial (or whatever time period works) to see if your intial feeling are valid or not.  If the employer declines, it doesn't sound like you really wanted the job to begin with so it's no great loss.  If the employer agrees then you will at least know definitively one way or the other for the next job.

Comment: Yes, however the problem is that I have a full time permanent job in the biggest Italian company, so I wouldn't leave that job "just for a try" even if the current job sucks...

Comment: No, I wouldn't want to do that either.

Answer (score 3):

I'm somewhat germophobic. I hate the idea of anyone touching my mouse and keyboard. I hate the idea of touching someone else's mouse and keyboard. I take the long way around the perimeter of the office complex rather than going through the courtyard to get to the cafeteria just so I won't have to touch any door handles.

On the other hand, I like the concept of programming in pairs. I might learn something interesting. Or I might instruct. Either way, it would be a good experience.

My proposal (for myself): do pair programming from a distance. Use Office Live Meeting and share your screen. Dude stays at his desk, I stay at mine.

Comment: Why not just bring your own mouse and keyboard? Or leave two hooked up to the same machine?

Comment: @Alex, possibly. But I generally feel the entire workspace has been contaminated. Don't ask me why. If you could explain insanity, it wouldn't be insane.

Comment: Reaaaaaly long USB cables? :)

Comment: But this still requires two people being constantly in sync, something I really don't like.

Answer (score 2):

Is there any way you can do some pair programming independently, to get a better feel for it?  There seem to be people who like pair programming, and people who don't, and before committing to a job that uses pair programming you really do want to have the feeling you can do it.

Alternately, you can talk to the hiring manager, or somebody in a similar position, and talk this over.  They may have use for a non-pair-programmer.  They may have experience with people who feel negative about pair programming.  Tell the manager why you're uncomfortable with pair programming, but emphasize that you have no experience and are very interested in the job.

Right now, you're in the best possible negotiating position with the company:  they've offered, and you haven't accepted yet.  The company has an interest in hiring you, and is very unlikely to drop you just because you need to talk to somebody in the company first.

Answer (score 0):

If you already know the technology, you will hate it.
But if you don't know the technology, you will learn it by PP.
If you don't know it and you don't do PP, then you will just sit there and not get anything done.

The worst case possible is if both parties know it and it turns into a race or a pissing contest.

Comment: Hi oregon111, it's great that you're trying to answer questions, but you've picked a bad tag to answer questions in: the [jobs] tag generally contains a lot of bad questions that we haven't gotten around to closing yet. Rather than trying to answer long-dead questions in a specific tag, consider looking at [the newest questions coming in](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions) and seeing which of those you can answer.